# Short way to serialize datetime with marshmallow

Tags: python, sql-server, serialization, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

Here is my situation: I store some datetime in MSSQL, which i get in my python application via SQLAlchemy, and then serialize it thru Marshmallow like this:

```
class MyVisitSchema(Schema):
    cafe = fields.Nested(CafeSchema)
    started_at = fields.DateTime()
    ended_at = fields.DateTime()

    class Meta:
        additional = ('duration',)
        ordered = True
```

But here the problem: after serialization i get something like `"started_at": "1994-05-20T00:00:00+00:00"` which says that UTC+0, but i store all my dates in DB without any timezone info, but in UTC+3.

I know that i can use `fields.Method()` to change output timezone, but it looks inconvenient. Any ideas how to make my serializer work as it should?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found some info in official documentaries. So, my issue can be solved using

`started_at = fields.DateTime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+03:00')`

hardcode a bit, but looks better than using additional function with `fields.Method()`

Answer (score 8):

If it does not work, use the keyword `format`

```
started_at = fields.DateTime(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+03:00')
```

Answer (score 6):

I would rather use `datetimeformat`, see: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/api_reference.html

Example:

```
class MyVisitSchema(Schema):
    cafe = fields.Nested(CafeSchema)
    started_at = fields.DateTime()
    ended_at = fields.DateTime()

    class Meta:
        additional = ('duration',)
        ordered = True
        # dateformat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
        dateformat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+03:00'
```

And I prefer to:

```
class BaseSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        dateformat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+03:00'


class MyVisitSchema(BaseSchema):
    cafe = fields.Nested(CafeSchema)
    started_at = fields.DateTime()
    ended_at = fields.DateTime()

    class Meta(BaseSchema.Meta):
        additional = ('duration',)
        ordered = True
```

Comment: I had to explicitly use the `DateTime(format='...')` syntax instead of the `Meta.dateformat` one for the release 3.0.0rc5. Did work before though.

Comment: `Meta.dateformat` has been renamed to `Meta.datetimeformat`; see the [upgrade docs](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrading.html#datetime-field-dateformat-meta-option-is-renamed-datetimeformat) for reference.